# ExecutionPolicy for domain account?

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

Have a windows service (azure local agent for a deployment group) that runs as domain account.  It's been discussed by others on my team, that setting unrestricted access for the localmachine isn't something that would be approved.  However, doing so lets the powershell script function without error.  The service needs elevated permissions because it runs a powershell script that stops a different windows service and deletes its files.  Is there a way to isolate the execution policy of this service or the domain account it runs under?

Comment: The Execution Policy is _not a security boundary_, don't treat it as one. What does "setting unrestricted access for the localmachine" mean in this context?

Comment: It means doing this  Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Comment: Ahh I see. "Unrestricted" in this context is not in reference to _access of any kind_ - it simply means PowerShell won't require signatures on scripts regardless of origin. You can configure per-user execution policy settings via group policy (Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows PowerShell)

Comment: Anybody can run `powershell -executionpolicy bypass whatever.ps1`.  It's only for not accidentally running scripts like in email attachments.

Comment: yes, but i dont think you can do that in the context of an azure pipeline?

Comment: @js2010 - duh, I just realized that your suggestion is something I have been doing plenty of times elsewhere (outside of an azure pipeline).  This could be done via a command line task - just feed in the parameters.  Am I correct to assume this is what you were referring to?

Comment: I don't have azure pipeline.  But powershell execution policy has nothing to do with preventing people from knowingly running powershell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the way I solved this was to put the script in a seperate file, rather than inline.  Then I was able to pass arguments (it mentions this in the docs, I just missed it).  Using -executionpolicy bypass
It works